# Memory Increasing and stringstream?

Tags: c++

According to a tutorial on writing dynamic text to screen, I was taught about `std::stringstream` and that you should use it for now, but I think there are better solutions because somebody said `stringstream` is not good on memory. The tutorial was never finished and unfortunately as a beginner it's like being left in the middle of an ocean without a boat. My program is exhibiting ever increasing **Process Memory** and by 5 minutes of run time, **Process Memory** is up to ~1gb. I would like to learn more about dynamic text in games and if `stringstream` is causing this problem

```
std::stringstream ss;
if (carrotCount < 20) { ss << "Carrots Found: " << carrotCount; }
else { ss << "Found All Carrots!"; }
label.getComponent<UILabel>().SetLabelText(ss.str(), "comic");
```

Comment: The memory should clear up when you leave the scope of the `ss` variable. Make sure it's not a global variable, you only use it in the area of the program that needs it.

Comment: The source of the problem is not apparent in the code you've shown. Please try to make and share a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Every '<<' operator you used for a stringstream variable will cause the latter to allocate memory for the operand. The more operators you use, the more memory will be allocated.

However, when the stringstream var is destroyed, all the memory it allocated will be released back to the system. This is easiest way to free memory.

Usually the stream var is allocated in the scope of a function, used in the function and gets automatically destroyed at return. This way you keep control over the memory use.

```
string getstring() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << 12 << " nights " << ...;
    return ss.str();
}
```

The above function will create the stringstream, use some meomry to create the string and destroyes it.

The problem might arise if you make the var global and continue streaming operands into it. Than it could easily behave as a memory leak and will claim more and more memory every time. So, do not do it. Or use other methods for cleaning or reusing its memory (i.e. re-allocatig or reusing streambuf).

Comment: I have an 'update()' function that runs every frame in a while loop, 'std::stringstream ss;' is in that.